Looking for a young-adult book about kids that get stuck in a cave
As near as I can remember, I read this book in 7th or 8th grade, so figure it would be written toward 10-15 year olds. I'm looking for a book where 2-4 (can't remember exactly) kids decide to explore an old cave/mine system. This isn't a fall-in-the-well rescue story. They get trapped and have to proceed forward to escape, but they were at least partially prepared because I remember them using the terms "belaying" and so on as they explore further. They overcome a number of obstacles and work their way through the cave to ultimately escape.
Any thoughts would be appreciated. My son is fascinated with caving and I thought it might be an interesting read for him.

That immediately reminds me of The Cave by Richard Church. But if that's right, there are no SF or F elements to it.

That is similar to the plot of Danny Dunn and the Fossil Cave.
Three children and two adults explore a cave. They get trapped when a natural bridge over a ravine collapses stranding them on the other side.  After further exploration they discover an alternative exit.
I don't recall that they said "belay" or not.
Even if it isn't the one you recall, it would be a good read for your son.
It does in fact have some SF elements in it. The professor has invented a see-through-walls device which they use in their exploration.

This sounds very much like the 1950 children's adventure story The Cave by Richard Church (retitled as Five Boys in a Cave for the American edition.)
The lead character is John Walters, who has been sent to spend the summer holidays with his uncle and aunt. He discovers the entrance to a complex of caves, and persuades his friends - the Tomahawk Club - to go on an expedition to explore them. The five boys include John's sensible next-door neighbor George Reynolds, an overweight boy named "Meaty" Sanders, Harold Soames, and the bossy self-appointed leader Alan Hobbs.
When they first enter the cave two boys descend a cliff by rope, which indeed involved a lot of "belaying". In a squabble the rope becomes detached, and the two groups of children have to first rejoin each other, and then find a way out. The cover blurb simply summarises the story as:

John Walters and his friends explore the tantalizing mysteries of a
previously undiscovered cave and in so doing learn a lot about
themselves.

